# how to hide MasterView on ladscape and portrait orientations UISplitViewController iOS7.1

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I am developing an app on iOS which displays a UISplitViewController. 
On portrait mode shows a button for showing/hidding the masterview controller (MenuPrincipalVC)
like this:

[image]
[image]

However when I rotate the view controller no matter if the menu was hidden on portrait view, it's always visible

[image]

I want the same behavior for master view on both orientations (landscape and portrait) I want the master view (MenuPrincipalVC) hidden and a button on the top for showing /hidding master view controller, this is my code:

This is for creating the SplitView and displaying it, masterViewController is always MenuPrincipalVC, but detailView depends of rightViewController:

```
#pragma mark *** UISplitViewController methods ***
-(void)showSplitViewControllerInView:(UIView *)view
            withDetailViewController:(id)rightViewController{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard        = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle: nil];

    UINavigationController  *leftNavController;
    UINavigationController  *rightNavController;

    MenuPrincipalVC  *leftViewController     = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuPrincipalVC"];
    leftViewController.title            = @" ";


    leftNavController                   = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftViewController];
    rightNavController                  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rightViewController];

    leftNavController.toolbarHidden                 = FALSE;
    rightNavController.toolbarHidden                = FALSE;
    leftNavController.navigationBar.translucent     = TRUE;
    rightNavController.navigationBar.translucent    = TRUE;
    leftNavController.toolbar.translucent           = FALSE;
    rightNavController.toolbar.translucent          = TRUE;

    UISplitViewController   *splitViewController    = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers             = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNavController, rightNavController, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate                    = rightViewController;

    if ([splitViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPresentsWithGesture:)]) {
        [splitViewController setPresentsWithGesture:NO];
    }

    view.window.rootViewController      = splitViewController;
}
#pragma -
```

on my rightViewController I set the following Methods:

```
#pragma mark - UISplitViewDelegate methods
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc{

    //Grab a reference to the popover
    self.popover                    = pc;

    barButtonItem.title             = [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FABars];
    NSDictionary *textAttributes    = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName
                                                                              size:TOOLBAR_ICONS_SIZE],
                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    UINavigationItem *navItem       = self.navigationItem;
    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
 invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem{


    //Remove the barButtonItem.
    [_navBarItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];

    //Nil out the pointer to the popover.
    _popover = nil;

}
#pragma mark -
```

thanks for the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all I had to do is to add next line of code to my detailed view controller:

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to simply to specifically set the width of the master view controller (and, of course, presentation controllers can always substitute the oddly behaving and difficult-to-use split-view approach).